# How can I spoof a jndi lookup for a datasource without a app server

Tags: java, datasource, jndi

I want to test some new functionality which is part of an internal web app. This new code uses a database connection normally provided by an app server (tomcat).

I do not want to recreate the entire web app on my local machine to test the new code, since I only need to run one function.

Does anyone know how I can 'spoof' a Context, or Datasource, to retrieve the database config, without actually creating a web app instance on a server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of Spring [SimpleNamingContextBuilder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/mock/jndi/SimpleNamingContextBuilder.html) and Apache [BasicDataSource](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html), you can do something like this (I usually have this in a static block in test classes that need JNDI):

```
BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClassName(db_driver_name);
dataSource.setUrl(db_connection_url);
dataSource.setUsername(db_username);
dataSource.setPassword(db_password);
SimpleNamingContextBuilder builder = new SimpleNamingContextBuilder();
builder.bind(jndi_name, dataSource);
builder.activate();
```

The value of `jndi_name` might look like this: `java:comp/env/jdbc/my-db`

Once this is set up, code that normally looks up the database connection via JNDI should work. The code above would for example work with this Spring config:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/my-db"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Lauri, how does the `JndiObjectFactoryBean` know to lookup `my-db` in the Spring directory?  Don't you have to provide the context environment?  In particular, in this environment, to what value would you set property `java.naming.factory.initial`?

Comment: Lauri, please see my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682732/what-value-should-property-java-naming-factory-initial-have-when-using-springs.

Comment: SimpleNamingContextBuilder is "Deprecated as of Spring Framework 5.2 in favor of complete solutions from third parties such as Simple-JNDI"

Answer (score 1):

The solutions listed here look a bit simpler than what I came up with about a year ago when I had to do the same thing. I basically made my own very simple DataSource implementation and adding it to a new Initial Context.

http://penguindreams.org/blog/running-beans-that-use-application-server-datasources-locally/

Answer (score 0):

With TomcatJNDI you can access every JNDI resource you configured within Tomcat as used to do in your web application. The code to achieve it is simple and looks like

```
TomcatJNDI tomcatJNDI = new TomcatJNDI();
tomcatJNDI.processContextXml(contextXmlFile);
tomcatJNDI.start();

DataSource ds = (DataSource) InitialContext.doLookup("java:comp/env/path/to/datasource")
```

[Go here to read more about it.](https://github.com/h-thurow/TomcatJNDI)