# How does an application that uses Spring's SimpleNamingContextBuilder know to search its directory for resources?

Tags: java, spring, jndi

How does an application that uses Spring's [`SimpleNamingContextBuilder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/mock/jndi/SimpleNamingContextBuilder.html) as its [JNDI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jndi/index.html) provider know to search its directory for resources?  What links the application to the Spring naming directory?  For example, how does the [`JndiObjectFactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/jndi/JndiObjectFactoryBean.html) bean in this earlier [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039725/how-can-i-spoof-a-jndi-lookup-for-a-datasource-without-a-app-server/3039780#3039780) know to find resource `my-db` in the Spring directory?  Doesn't `JndiObjectFactoryBean` require a context environment with property `java.naming.factory.initial` set to some implementation of interface [`InitialContextFactory`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html)?  What should the value of `java.naming.factory.initial` be when using `SimpleNamingContextBuilder` as the JNDI provider?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java runtime class [`NamingManager`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/spi/NamingManager.html) serves as the link between a Java application and its naming directory.  When a `SimpleNamingContextBuilder` [activates](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#KiMld_NTZZU/trunk/force-com-cloud-converter-old/src/java/org/springframework/mock/jndi/SimpleNamingContextBuilder.java&q=lang:java%20class:SimpleNamingContextBuilder%20function:activate&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc&l=137), it installs itself to static member [`InitialContextFactoryBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/spi/InitialContextFactoryBuilder.html) in `NamingManager`.  When the application creates an [`InitialContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html) to retrieve the JNDI context, class `InitialContext` delegates to NamingManager, which in turn asks the `IntialContextFactoryBuilder` (in this case, `SimpleNamingContextBuilder`) to create an [`IntialContextFactory`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/spi/InitialContextFactory.html), which ultimately creates the `InitialContext`.

`JndiObjectFactoryBean` doesn't need an explicit context environment because `SimpleNamingContextBuilder` provides the `InitialContextFactory` to the `NamingManager` and `JndiObjectFactoryBean` uses the `NamingManager` to retrieve its resources.  So, in the earlier answer, `JndiObjectFactoryBean` "knows" to search the Spring naming directory for resource `my-db` because `SimpleNamingContextBuilder` has established itself as the JNDI provider in the `NamingManager`.

Answer (score 13):

In a nutshell, If want to mock JNDI tree with mock InitialContext  in unit tests , SimpleNamingContextBuilder can be used.  I instantiated SimpleNamingContextBuildeit in a startup method of test and successfully creates a in-memory InitialContext.
e.g. in a spring test class..

```
@BeforeClass
    public static void setupJndi() throws Exception {
    SimpleNamingContextBuilder.emptyActivatedContextBuilder();
    Context context = new InitialContext();
    context.bind("java:comp/env/jms/ConnectionFactory",myJmsConnectionFactory);
   }
```

Comment: Good example!  This illustrates my point that when you activate a `SimpleNamingContextBuilder`, it installs itself as the default JNDI context.

Comment: Similar as here: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework/spring-test/4.3.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/mock/jndi/SimpleNamingContextBuilder.html